# Java Drag drop and netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, drag-and-drop

I create the GUI using the netbeans,I need to adding Drag and drop components to my project.but I tired of doing this.netbeans is not supporting (or not dragging correctly)drag and drop while the programme in the running.so I need your helps?

Comment: I meant In the programme I added the toolbox of Tools.(like lables with the images)I need to drag and drop in that components another Jpanel. thanks

Comment: From the wealth of detail in your question, the best suggestion I can think of is 'use another IDE'.  As it stands, it seems to be 'not a real question'.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Netbeans bring up any kind of error (like the component can't be initialized or something??).

If so you can find the logs in `{user}/.netbeans/{version}/var/log/messages.log`

On Windows 7, that would be `/users/{user}/.netbeans/{version}/var/log/messages.log`

Netbeans 7.2 moved it to .AppData/local (I think - check roam if it's not there)

This will give you an idea of what the error is (includes a nice stack trace)

Also remember that components in the palette require a empty constructor

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop features have been lessened/removed from NetBeans' current version.

Try using NetBeans version 6.1 to 6.8, which support full Drag and Drop functionality.